# How can I pick only 10% of requests in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a new functionality which I don't want to cut lose in one go. We would like to just pick 10% of the requests to hit this functionality. I wonder if I can do that easily in JavaScript?

On top of my head I'm thinking of using Array to store the requests and pick just a portion of it. Is there a better way to do this?

I have this piece of code from Express

```
doSomething: function(request, response) {

   // new functionality  << how can I control how many requests hitting this block of code? Like 10 percent of the requests

   // old functionality
}
```

I don't care if the rest of the requests are dropped. We have 2500 requests/s right now and I'm afraid that if I hit this functionality in one go things will fall apart. It's a quite intensive computing code.

Comment: I honestly have no idea, but maybe `if((Math.floor(Math.random()*100)%10) == 0 ) //execute code?` could be a good starting point?

Comment: Actually that's a good idea.

Comment: if ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) === 0)) ...    as a naive approach..

Comment: This looks like a standard A/B test. Make sure to multiply your measured results by 100% to see if this test (B) works better than your current site (A). If so adopt it for the current site. If not, rework it. Maybe it could be tagged as an "A/B Test"?

Comment: You don't need flooring or multiplications. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this pretty straightforward? Or am I not understanding something in your question...

```
var numRequests=0;
//snip
doSomething: function(request, response) {
    if (numRequests++ %10 === 0){
       //new functionality
    }
    else{
       //old
    }        
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the simplest solution. Of course, some disclaimers apply. This is not predictable or scalable. For a more permanent solution, use a load-balancer.

Comment: Why isn't it predictable? Every 9 out of 10 requests get the old functionality. Seems predictable to me. :)

Comment: Yes, in a single server environment it is predictable. Consider if you have two app servers though. The processes will each have their own counter, so sometimes you will get 2 requests through at once, and sometimes it will skip 18 requests before serving one.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, that's still pretty predictable though. You are still guaranteed that in 20 those requests there WILL be 18 old and 2 new. But yes, where *exactly* they show up is unknown, so if that kind of precision is needed, a load balancer or *some* kind of shared state is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course don't have state...

```
doSomething: function(request, response) {
   if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
     // new functionality  
   } else {
     // old functionality
   }
}
```

Please don't use this for some kind of A/B testing or canary deployments. For that you'd rather need N instances and slowly route to the new one.

I am using the above for example for database calls I'd don't need to do every time the route gets hit.